# How to copy files from local computer to Yun with scp?

Tags: arduino-yun, ssh

I need to transfer files from my local machine to my Arduino Yun.

I have tried:

```
scp /Users/SSCirrus/Documents/index.html root@arduino.local:/root
scp ~/Users/SSCirrus/Documents/index.html root@arduino.local:/root
# No such file or directory (referring to my desktop)
```

I have confirmed that the filepath is accurate. What's wrong here?

Comment: Try `~/Documents/index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `~/Documents/index.html`

The `~` represents the current user's home directory, so `~/Documents` is the Documents folder for the current user.  It means you don't have to make sure you have spelled the user's home directory exactly right.

Other options are:

- `$HOME/Documents/index.html`
- `Documents/index.html` (if you are in your home directory)
- `cd ~/Documents` then just use `index.html`

... the list goes on ...